# Brace initialization with constructor for class with virtual function

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, aggregate, list-initialization

I understand aggregates cannot have virtual member functions, yet this code compiles

```
struct B {
    B(int yIn) :y(yIn) {}
    int y;
    virtual void f() {}
};

B b = {3};
```

Is brace initialization different than aggregate initialization, or is this class a valid aggregate because of its constructor?

Answer (score 4):

Yes `B` is not an [aggregate type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Explanation), which can't have virtual member functions. So `B b = {3};` won't perform [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), but [copy-list-initialization (since C++11)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) instead, as the effect, the constructor `B::B(int)` is called to initialize the object.

> - Otherwise, the constructors of `T` are considered, in two phases:
>
>   - ...
>   - If the previous stage does not produce a match, all constructors of `T` participate in [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Implicit_conversion_sequence_in_list-initialization) against the set of arguments that consists of the elements of the braced-init-list, with the restriction that only non-narrowing conversions are allowed. If this stage produces an explicit constructor as the best match for a copy-list-initialization, compilation fails (note, in simple copy-initialization, explicit constructors are not considered at all).